# jp@gc - PerfMon Metrics Collector : Analysing the process combined CPU usage in percentage

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, perfmon

I'm performing 500 concurrent users signup using jmeter. When I analyse **CPU usage by process Id** in perfmon metrics, it goes beyond 400%. 
There is 4 cores in my system. How it is possible?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Your question contains the answer itself, as per [top command manual](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/top.1.html)

> 1. **%CPU  --  CPU Usage**
>
>    The task's share of the elapsed CPU time since the last screen
>             update, expressed as a percentage of total CPU time.
>
>    In a true SMP environment, if a process is multi-threaded and top
>             is not operating in Threads mode, **amounts greater than 100% may
>             be reported**.  You toggle Threads mode with the `H' interactive
>             command.

So for instance if you have 4 core system and each core is 50% busy you will get 200% CPU usage.

The maximum would be `number of cores * 100%`, in particular your case it means that your system lacks CPU so this is probably the [bottleneck](https://www.quora.com/What-is-bottleneck-in-performance-testing). You should either consider/suggest migrating to the system which has more cores or more CPU power or use [profiling tools](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profiling_(computer_programming)) to detect the most "CPU hungry" part of your application and refactor it.

More information:

- [What does >100% CPU utilization mean?](https://www.quora.com/What-does-100-CPU-utilization-mean)
- [How to Monitor Your Server Health & Performance During a JMeter Load Test](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-monitor-your-server-health-performance-during-jmeter-load-test)